# need db alias(connection_name) in django.db.backends sql query debug log

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging

I am able to print the sql logs using the logger configuration in django settings as below when I have `DEBUG=True`

```
'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
         },
```

> [14/Jun/2017 19:50:19] DEBUG [django.db.backends:execute] (0.213)
>   SELECT "django_session"."session_key",
>   "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM
>   "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."session_key" =
>   E'79a9c6354bf0f30967adbcb0d572707a'  AND
>   "django_session"."expire_date" > E'2017-06-14 19:50:18.019996' );
>   
> args=('79a9c6354bf0f30967adbcb0d572707a', u'2017-06-14
>   19:50:18.019996')

But the information only I get is **duration, sql & params**
Referring [django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-db-backends)

I have multiple DBs in my settings.py to connect and I am using `DATABASE_ROUTERS` to route my queries to master/slave replication.
But I am unable to find the way to log the **DB alias (connection_name)** to the logger.
Is there any way to print all queries with **connection_name** without using [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar#django-debug-toolbar) in a log file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to log number of queries from each database. There is a way to do that without using any custom debug toolbar.Write your custom middleware and log the queries as shown below.

```
from django.db import connections

for con in connections: 
    print con,len(connections[con].queries), connections[con].queries
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @vidya-sagar I got to know that all the queries executed during the session is available using connections instead of using connection which eventually was giving me few queries earlier and that was related to default db obviously.